# Excel VBA Shell.Namespace returns Nothing

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I'm trying to extract a .CAB file using Excel VBA, but I'm getting the following error:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

I usually get this when I forget to use `Set` with an Object, but I've checked for that.

All examples I can find are variations on this theme:

```
Private Function DeCab(vSource, vDest) As Long
    Dim objShell, objFileSource, objFileDest As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFileSource = objShell.Namespace(vSource)
    Set objFileDest = objShell.Namespace(vDest)
    Call objFileDest.MoveHere(objFileSource.Items, 4 Or 16) 'Fails here
    Decab = objFileDest.Items.Count
End Function
```

It's not failing on the `Set` line, but it's setting both `objFileSource` and `objFileDest` to `Nothing` even though I've confirmed `vSource` and `vDest` exist.

To confirm it has nothing to do with the .CAB file, I've also tried it without setting `objFileSource` and checking the value of `objFileDest` after it's set. It still returns `Nothing`. Why would that be? I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit, running Office 2010.

Comment: Are vSource and vDest both string variables?  Try Variant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your parameters must be submitted as Variant, not String

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim src, dest                      '<< works
    'Dim src As String, dest As String '<< gives the error you see

    src = "D:\temp\test.zip"
    dest = "D:\temp\unzip"

    DeCab src, dest

End Sub
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Tim's answer is correct. I found an alternative, as well:

```
Private Function DeCab(vSource, vDest) As Long
    Dim objShell, objFileSource, objFileDest As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFileSource = objShell.Namespace((vSource)) '<-extra parentheses
    Set objFileDest = objShell.Namespace((vDest)) '<-extra parentheses
    Call objFileDest.MoveHere(objFileSource.Items, 4 Or 16) 'Fails here
    Decab = objFileDest.Items.Count
End Function
```

When you place an object in parentheses in VBA, it returns the default value of the object. Apparently, `objShell.Namespace` can't handle a pointer. It can only handle a string literal. Changing the signature to the following also works if you're passing in Strings:

```
Private Function DeCab(ByVal vSource, ByVal vDest) As Long
```

Comment: I know it's a bit older but I tried to find a solution for my question which seemed to be the same, but turns out to have a flavor added:

Comment: I used everything above (already had set variables to variants) and tried the parentheses but had the same error. 
Looking at every detail, I found out that the foldername is first detected as 'my documents' and can't be set because the folder's real name is 'documents'.
is this related or should I create a separate question?

Comment: I'd create a new question, just because this is old. :)

Answer (score 0):

for my case. i used the shell

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
x= oShell.xxxx
y= oShell.Namespace(x)
```

in two different lines. seems like i'll need to re initialized to able to use on second line. eg

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
x= oShell.xxxx
y= CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(x)
```

then only it works.